# Please provide guidance in understanding recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int countX(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'x') {
        return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));
    } else {
        return countX(str.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Given an input String of "xxx", the method above shall return 3. 
I understand the flow of the method, the line *"return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));"* adds one if an 'x' is found. What I don't understand is how does that return value carry over to the next iteration/recursion? I don't see the value of the increment stored anywhere.

Comment: Nothing is carried over. You just return `1 + <result of recursive call>`, where the "result" must be fully evaluated first before the `return` is finished. The "result" itself might return `0`, `1 + <result of recursive call>` or `<result of recursive call>`

Comment: Recursive calls are not treated any different than other calls. Each call gets their own set of local bound variables eg. `str` is a different binding so if I do `countX("hey") + countX("ho")` the two calls to `countX` will have each their own `str`. AFAICS the base case returns `0` for an empty list and the default case does `1 + <recursion step>` when the first char is `x` and just `<recursion step>` if it isn't. Thus `countX("xxx")` ends up as `1 + (1 + (1 + 0))`. You should do this on pen and paper.

Comment: Use a debugger and debug your code. You'll learn more than by asking here.

Comment: @JamesZ I have limited English. Hence my need for an actual human being to help me understand. No need to be sassy about it.

Comment: So, you are not so good in English, so that's why you can't use debugger, so you ask in StackOverflow, in English? And StackOverflow is only for questions, not asking for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the line  `return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));`
Now suppose that str was "xx", so the substring passed to the recursive call is "x".
So in that call, since the first character is 'x', it again executes

```
return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));
```

in the next recursive call, the substring is empty, so it returns zero to the previous call, which then returns (1+0) to its previous call, which returns ( 1 + (1 +0) ) to the initial call of the method, so the result for the String "xx" becomes 1+1+0 = 2.